# How to hide a hotspot button based on sender In Lotus Notes 8.5?

Tags: lotus-notes

I am managing an email newsletter that is distributed through Lotus Notes. At the bottom, I have 4 hotspot buttons for "Subscribe," "Unsubscribe," "Forward to a Colleague," and "Archives."

Subscribe and Unsubscribe use @MailSend to email me the sub/unsub request. However, I am getting a lot of people who click "Subscribe" even when they are already subscribed.

I'm looking for a way to hide the Subscribe button when the email sender is my newsletter email address.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of anyway that you could hide the Subscribe button from some people unless maybe you have them in a public group and have it set to hide if they are in that group or something.

One easy thing you could do is to move the subscribe button to the end so it would be Unsubscribe, Forward, Archive, Subscribe or maybe put 'forward' as the first option.

Another thing you could do is above the buttons, put a line that says 'You are currently subscribed' on the emails or 'If you received this from 'your name', you are subscribed, if you receive this as a forward, click below to subscribe'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hide-when formula on the paragraph containing the Subscribe button, however you need to understand that in Notes a paragraph includes everything on the same line unless you use a table, in which case the paragraph is limited to the table cell.  So you could put your buttons in four cells of a table, and apply this hide-when formula to the subscribe button:

```
From="my newsletter address";
```

Note that you will have to exactly match the address as it appears in the From header field.

Hide-when formulas are entered by positioning the cursor anywhere in the paragraph that you want hidden, and bringing up the Text properties box.  If you're in Notes 8.x, you can do that by selecting Properties from the Text menu. (I don't recall the menu path on older versions, and I usually just use Ctrl-J as a keyboard shortcut.)  Then select the second to last tab in the properties box, click on the checkbox labeled 'Hide paragraph if formula is true', and enter the formula in the box below that.

Comment: This gets me much closer to what I was looking for -- thank you. I have a subscribe and an unsubscribe button, so I tagged the unsub button:
'From="my newsletter address"; '

And the subscribe button:
'From!="my newsletter address"; '

If I send the newsletter from "my newsletter address," it hides the subscribe button. From "my personal address," it hides the unsubscribe button.

Ideally, the Subscribe button would reappear if I receive the message from "my newsletter address" and FORWARD it to a 3rd party (now from "my personal address"). Any ideas on how to achieve this last step?

Comment: If I'm interpreting you correctly, you want the subscribe button visible if the message comes from "my personal address" and only from your personal address.  I.e., a subscribed newsletter recipient doesn't see it, and if a subscriber forwards the message to a third party, the 3rd party doesn't see it either.  They only see it if they receive it from you.  If that's correct, see my next comment.

Comment: It is often useful to think in terms of a "see-when formula" instead of a hide-when.  That's because we very often express our requirements in terms of what we want to see, rather than what we want to hide.  That's what you've done here for the subscribe button.  A see-when formula is equivalent to putting a logical not around a hide-when formula.  So in the case of the subscribe button, you want a recipient to see it if the message came from your personal address, therefore what you enter in the hide-when formula is !(From="my personal address")

Comment: I want the subscribe button visible when anyone forwards the email, but not when it is sent to the main list. Using the formulas I stated above, if I send the original from my newsletter address, recipients see Unsub, and don't see Subscribe. That's perfect. But, when they forward it, I need that behavior to reverse, so a third party sees Subscribe, not Unsubscribe. It may be that I need to use a more complex way of forwarding, since what seems to be happening is that the button code is not reprocessed when forwarded. I apologize for my lack of familiarity with Notes coding!! :-)

Comment: Okay... If the behavior is correct when you send from the newsletter address and you want the opposite behavior when the message is forwarded, then I think it's fair to re-express that this way: you want the opposite behavior when the message is sent from any address except the newsletter address.  I.e., the recipient always sees Subscribe or Unsubscribe, but never both.  That would imply that the hide-when on the Unsubscribe button should be the opposite (i.e., logical not) of the hide-when on the subscribe button.  So that would be: !(From="my newsletter address).

Comment: Yes. And if I cut and paste the newsletter, that works -- the proper button shows up in both occasions. But if someone receives the newsletter and forwards it, it maintains the behavior it was sent with. So send from "my newsletter address" to "userA" then "userA" forwards to "userB" and it still displays Unsub and not Sub, as though it were sent from "my newsletter address." I think because it's not reevaluating the hide-when rules, it's just pushing forward the output from the first processing. That's where I keep getting stuck.

Comment: The hide-when formulas should be re-evaluated every time the message is displayed, and I don't think forwarding should change that unless there's a format conversion occurring -- butt if the format is changing from Notes rich text to MIME then I would also expect the forwarded button to be non-functional.   Apart from that, the only thing I can think of is that hide-when formulas in table cells were notoriously flaky prior to Notes 7.0.2 (I think), so if you're on an earlier version that might be a factor.